# Migrate to AndroidX button in Android Studio is disabled when using buildSrc

Tags: android-studio, androidx

After I changed my project to use buildSrc to better management dependencies

*inside buildSrc/build.gradle.kts*

```
plugins {
  `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
   jcenter()
}
```

**The problem is when we have to migrate to AndroidX the Refactor -> "Migrate to AndroidX..." button is disabled and after I remove buildSrc/build.gradle.kts the button is active** **Surprise!!!** anyone know how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: My workaround is rollback all my build.gradle files to use plain text in dependencies, and restore it to use buildSrc again after migration.

Comment: Thanks mate you saved my day, also I suggest that you post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My workaround is rollback all my build.gradle files to use plain text in dependencies, and restore it to use buildSrc again after migration